# How do I test my Apple Watch app with my iPad app?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, watchkit

It appears that only iPhone simulators are available when running my Apple Watch app, how can I test it with my iPad app?

Answer (score 3):

Original answer:

> Since it says "iPhone 5 or newer required" on their website, i guess
>   you won't be able to pair it with an iPad. Also doesn't make too much
>   sense since you won't carry around your iPad in your pocket.

As pointed out in the comments, this is wrong.
I referred to the Apple website where it says "Apple Watch is designed to partner with iPhone. To use it, you'll need an iPhone 5 or later."
However this actally wasn't your question.

Anyways: i couldn't figure out a way to accomplish what you want. Probably the apps mentioned in the comments are going to be updated before launch to also run on an iPhone.

Comment: This is an anecdotal answer without much fact.  Search this page for "iPad" and you'll see multiple apps that advertise integration with the iPad from the Apple Watch: https://www.apple.com/watch/app-store-apps/  And furthermore, some of the apps cited on that page are iPad only.